# How can I make time series plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I need to contrast the my kl variable against the rtfpna variable across year and
Contrast kl against ly, like this one:

[enter link description here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Labour-productivity-capital-productivity-and-the-capital-labour-ratio_fig2_4767846)

I will be comparing labor productivity and labor intensity of output.
y axis can be cumulative percent change. but i could not handle it. how can I plot it with ggplot?

my code is here so far:

```
    data_long ＜- melt(brazil, id.vars = "year") 

ggplot(data_long,                           
       aes(x = year,
           y = value,
           col = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

but I can see only kl variable. I want to make Y axis percent change and other variables also should fit the graph. Can you help me please?

My data:

```
structure(list(year = c(1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 
1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 
1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 
1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019), rtfpna = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.805425643920898, 0.819433450698853, 0.815486192703247, 
0.850582480430603, 0.861791253089905, 0.875620603561401, 0.89727258682251, 
0.9761683344841, 0.981472432613373, 1.00725114345551, 1.01003503799438, 
1.03612756729126, 1.0297394990921, 1.04712808132172, 1.11110424995422, 
1.10885286331177, 1.15965461730957, 1.2095251083374, 1.26581692695618, 
1.29986226558685, 1.32612347602844, 1.31677484512329, 1.36736083030701, 
1.31742632389069, 1.31152975559235, 1.36835289001465, 1.44977855682373, 
1.3178858757019, 1.26234591007233, 1.19983005523682, 1.22336530685425, 
1.24787294864655, 1.29066753387451, 1.28447079658508, 1.23783981800079, 
1.24178087711334, 1.1565774679184, 1.14836263656616, 1.12104296684265, 
1.14489555358887, 1.17703557014465, 1.18664479255676, 1.19274938106537, 
1.18882584571838, 1.16212427616119, 1.11827838420868, 1.11366415023804, 
1.10503828525543, 1.09412336349487, 1.08263611793518, 1.09423959255219, 
1.0970253944397, 1.09963548183441, 1.13645040988922, 1.15163838863373, 
1.12394869327545, 1.15129041671753, 1.13314604759216, 1.11766314506531, 
1.11116170883179, 1.08192467689514, 1.03259932994843, 0.999256372451782, 
1, 0.987977206707001, 0.97051203250885), kl = c(13384.1146710151, 
13905.4317379675, 14543.3115078026, 14738.6663258408, 15117.962401934, 
15419.2732598875, 15582.9626343674, 16085.4967356683, 16470.0290787947, 
17186.6320696312, 17663.8533325066, 18305.7390664852, 18955.4212727199, 
19315.4476234411, 19778.6872677136, 20348.143023004, 20964.6185147953, 
21337.7172335079, 22004.2096224082, 23421.5943475649, 24886.7078912714, 
25589.876623367, 26583.4606170811, 26239.5734578624, 28497.7343843658, 
30784.0131388709, 32515.4201783311, 31395.0283935978, 32093.398044122, 
34812.517528794, 38194.9191254873, 39465.210653577, 40021.7247790243, 
41469.4399059998, 42145.3537526209, 41741.4306643921, 43918.1782180909, 
45757.3252585928, 47590.1711487569, 50280.4650471358, 52346.3151598796, 
56134.2221114178, 59940.6612822668, 63192.8950090397, 67099.8483065609, 
71056.715493274, 76253.2274594481, 78581.3280983498, 81906.5419803117, 
79683.3838413336, 78739.2803798882, 80408.9285072658, 79209.1317351792, 
80408.8751312901, 79383.8858473091, 80864.9278521795, 84884.4177678533, 
95936.2213458752, 111507.260345482, 132100.473013969, 149872.417184893, 
159919.296530163, 158413.078594305, 155715.691961547, 153957.348437576, 
150923.996107035, 149018.775987358, 148813.98192679, 147188.2646575, 
145569.946224593), ly = c(0.000192081975169606, 0.000191676568301465, 
0.000178150124840108, 0.000177261540902725, 0.000167979888410041, 
0.000160545551853635, 0.00015930510632854, 0.000150759109766604, 
0.00014667475219325, 0.000144362792203364, 0.000135573558523505, 
0.000121862442568487, 0.00011598817899593, 0.000111137742890844, 
0.000108993752154928, 0.000105077808249478, 0.000102753141141034, 
9.71157787488221e-05, 9.02721802564341e-05, 9.11326210372743e-05, 
8.21529112879634e-05, 7.74747056306122e-05, 7.29418232239867e-05, 
7.2079948603802e-05, 6.78989033930588e-05, 6.68288701556521e-05, 
6.32167379740309e-05, 6.77958027491811e-05, 6.72849300785159e-05, 
6.18199857841665e-05, 6.10598843540433e-05, 6.13785967200655e-05, 
6.322150328238e-05, 6.53099177091729e-05, 6.52259743232825e-05, 
6.65807146866565e-05, 5.98779813321663e-05, 6.00058097132319e-05, 
6.16151015847246e-05, 6.15075726816595e-05, 6.4564989654978e-05, 
5.89804834703621e-05, 5.72009942535745e-05, 5.36571443523847e-05, 
4.80415136646997e-05, 4.15694481109486e-05, 3.39854234488139e-05, 
3.56472305678744e-05, 3.70922586244233e-05, 4.04059213895776e-05, 
4.12019794519667e-05, 4.15933413003583e-05, 4.29868360536339e-05, 
4.37847891035929e-05, 4.38000521738722e-05, 4.3492450941185e-05, 
4.11081427705436e-05, 3.71200694703033e-05, 3.39197004604689e-05, 
3.28454929411177e-05, 2.93904895197602e-05, 2.70128143683769e-05, 
2.73584030910398e-05, 2.75700693997243e-05, 2.81523914533772e-05, 
2.99867196457755e-05, 3.0914562397841e-05, 3.04839029945696e-05, 
3.02719475151839e-05, 3.05049823911369e-05)), row.names = c(NA, 
-70L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Explain what you want in terms of the column names in your data and provide code of your best attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your three series have completely different scales. `ly` has values that are approximately 10,000 times smaller than `rtfpna`, and `kl` has values that are about 100,000 times greater than `rtfpna`. When you try to plot all the series together, the y axis will be large enough for you to see the values for all the series. That means it needs to range from 0 to 350,000. However, since the values for `ly` and `rtfna` are between 0 and 2, then they will sit along the very bottom pixel of your image. (if your plot is 1,000 pixels high, then anything with a value under 350 will be in the bottom pixel of the plot).

We can get all the series to appear on the plot if we divide `kl` by 100,000 and multiply `ly` by 10,000:

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- brazil %>%
  mutate(kl = kl / 100000, ly = ly * 10000) %>%
  pivot_longer(-year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() 

p
```

[image]

But now of course the problem is that the y axis scale does not give the correct readings for `ly` or `kl`. We can fix this to some extent by adding a second axis for `kl`

```r
p + scale_y_continuous(name = 'rtfpna', 
                       sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x*200000, name = 'kl',
                                           labels = scales::comma))
```

[image]

But the `ly` line still doesn't have a scale representing it.

It's generally considered poor practice to even have two different y axis scales on the same plot let alone three, and although there are hacks to achieve this, it's probably not worth doing.

Your alternatives are to use facets:

```r
brazil %>%
  pivot_longer(-year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(name~., scales = 'free_y')
```

[image]

Or use a log axis to fit everything in:

```r
brazil %>%
  pivot_longer(-year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = 10^seq(-4, 5), labels = scales::comma)
```

[image]

Personally, I think facets are the way to go here.

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Okay, I am just trying to learn the mindset. It is hard to combine these 3 variable in a time series graph because their scales are different. They are extremes to compare. So, instead we used facets and we did not play with the scale of the dataset, we just showed it one after the other so that we can compare these variables across years. Right?

Comment: In the facets, yes. To get all three lines in a single panel you need to transform the data and add an extra axis, but this makes for a more confusing plot. The facets make things much clearer and don't require you to rescale your data @emilyy